# How to resolve a Promise.all() despite some rejections?

Tags: javascript

I am still quite new to this and perhaps `promise.all()` is not what I need, or maybe I am just doing this the wrong way to begin with, but I have a bunch of resources I am trying to fetch via HTTP.

Some of them will not be available to certain account types, so I figure, let the ones that fail due to server-side permission fail and just get on with it.

```
promise.all([
    http.get('bookings'),
    http.get('users'),
    http.get('listings')
])
.then(valuse => assign(values))
.catch(err => makeAnError(err))
```

So assuming `http.get('users')` fails, the promise.all will reject and none of the other values will be assigned as the resolve function to assign those values never runs.

What are some suggested solutions to this?

Comment: simple answer, handle individual rejections

Comment: The `async` package for Node has some good control flow capabilities that may be of use, in particular the `async.series` function.

Comment: @m_callens - `asyncjs + Promises == bad design` (I'm not referring to async/await) - besides, `async.series` performs the actions in series, whereas the code in the question performs them in parallel (as much as that's possible in js)

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way

```
Promise.prototype.always = function always() {
    return this.then(result=>({fulfilled: true, result}), reason=>({fulfilled: false, reason}));
};
```

then your code

```
promise.all([
    http.get('bookings').always(),
    http.get('users').always(),
    http.get('listings').always()
])
.then(values => assign(values)) // assign needs to check each value.fulfilled == true before using value.result
.catch(err => makeAnError(err))
```